# WPF User Control design time accessing internal user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a User Control A which contains within it another User Control B.

User Control A has a dependency property `DeviceColour`. This determines the Colour of the internal User Control B.

The registration of this Dependency property is as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DeviceColourProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DeviceColour",
              typeof(vhBase.DeviceColours),typeof(ucBaseDevice),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(vhBase.DeviceColours.Gray,
              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,new PropertyChangedCallback(DeviceColourProperty_PropertyChanged)));

public  vhBase.DeviceColours DeviceColour
{
    get { return (vhBase.DeviceColours)GetValue(DeviceColourProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DeviceColourProperty, value); }
}

private static void DeviceColourProperty_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ucBaseDevice device = (ucBaseDevice)obj;
    device.VisualDevice.DeviceColour = (vhBase.DeviceColours)e.NewValue;      
}
```

In the above property change event, `VisualDevice` is a property that points to the Internal User Control B as shown below:

```
public override vhBase VisualDevice
{
    get {  return vhMain; }
}
```

`vhMain` is User Control B which I can see and manipulate in the XAML designer.

The problem I'm having at design time, is that `VisualDevice` appears to be returning NULL i.e. `vhMain`, the user control is null and therefore "object reference not set to an instance....".

This works at runtime, but I need it to also work at design time.

As you've perhaps realised, I don't know too much about DP and, well, WPF in general and I'm finding myself going around in circles.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've make a simple sample of what-i-think-is-right way to bind child's property to parent's one.
I used the Color property as an example, but that's the same for every propery type.

There are two user controls: `ControlB` with DP 'Colour' and `ControlA` with DP `DeviceColour`. `ControlB` just painting its background to the specified color:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ControlB" <!--skipped--> Name="controlB">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ElementName=controlB, Path=Colour}" />
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And there is how to bind that properties from XAML in ControlA:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ControlA" <!--skipped--> Name="controlA">
    <Grid>
        <my:ControlB Colour="{Binding ElementName=controlA, Path=DeviceColour}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And there is how to use ControlA:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" <!--skipped-->>
    <Grid>
        <my:ControlA DeviceColour="Green" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```